# EWS Delegated access - The specified object was not found

Tags: ews-managed-api

Trying to access a mailbox folder using another generic account which has permissions to the target mailbox and folder. FindFolders gets the folders and total count but when trying to FindItems it raises the error.
The specified object was not found in the store., Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information. The mailbox may have been moved recently.

Suspecting the multi-region/geo issue but this was resolved before by using X-AnchorMailbox which doesnt work now.

```
var folder = _exchangeService.FindFolders(folderId, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.FolderClass, "IPF.Contact"), new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName == "Contacts");

var items = folder.FindItems(view);
var items = Folder.Bind(_exchangeService, folder.Id).FindItems(view);
var items = _exchangeService.FindItems(folder.Id, view);
```

Different methods of finding the items returns the same error.